# What's the most efficient way to filter out items with member that don't contain the terms?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

What's the most efficient way to write the following query?

Get 5 items that have member `member` that contains any of these items: `['item1', 'item2']`.

```
should: [{ terms : {member: ['item1', 'item2'] } }]
```

If you find only 3 items, get 2 more where `member` is **empty**.

How do I finish this query?

Comment: can you provide your mapping and sample docs, so that its easy to reproduce and test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a should clause with term and not exists. So it will fetch documents where field member matches input query and where field doesn't exist. You can pass size to get top 5 documents from result

```
{
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "member": [
              "1",
              "2",
              "3"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "member"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the first time I'm seeing nested `bool` clause. Could you please explain or provide a reference?

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski bool query is a container to combine  "AND","OR"and"NOT" queries . You can get more info here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: I've been through those docs, but they still do not explain how to nest the bool clauses. I'm still confused as to how are the bool clauses composed/nested together.

Comment: For what it's worth, I finally tried your solution and it works. Thanx! If you could please try to explain how to read/understand these bool operations, that would be awesome!

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski bool helps to combine complex queries. It provides options for "OR" , "AND", "NOT" queries You can get more info here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: I've been through those docs, but they still do not explain how to nest the bool clauses.

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski bool has four functions "Should","Must","Must_Not", "Filter". All these take array of queries. Any query in these clauses can again be a bool clause

Comment: Let's try with an example. You used "should" as the first function. However, since the whole condition HAS to be satisfied, I would expect a "must" function. Could you help me understand that?

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski ex1 "Must":[{query1},{query2}}] returns documents which match both query1 and query2. Should :[{query1},{query2}] returns document which match either query1  or query2. In the answer documents are returned which either match first or second query so either member has any of the value [1,2,3] or field member doesn't exist

Comment: Thanx. That helped a lot. But you can surely understand how that it is counter-intuitive. What I expected when using 'should' is "Prefer documents that satisfy the condition, but don't disregard the rest". Instead, we're getting something quite different. How did you come to understand it that way, where in the docs is that explained?

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski Should when used alone filters the documnet when used with must , mustnot, and filter  doesn't filter the document only boosts them